# Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-methods, paypal-express, terms-and-conditions

I need your help. I'm running Magento CE 1.9 and every time someone places an order I get the email saying:

Payment transaction failed. Reason Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order. Checkout Type onepage

However, the order gets placed. I tested it myself and I get the same email even though I agree to terms and conditions. So far I noticed this only with PayPal.

Does anybody know what could it be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

May be it is useful for you

skin/frontend/base/default/js/checkout/review.js

```
 _bindElementChange : function(input){
        Event.observe(input, 'change', this._onElementChange.bindAsEventListener(this))
    },
```

change to:

```
 _bindElementChange : function(input){
        if (input.identify().substr(0, 9) != 'agreement'){        
            Event.observe(input, 'change', this._onElementChange.bindAsEventListener(this))    
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me:

1. Rename `paypal.xml` to `paypal._xml` within "app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/layout/" (Magento 1.9)
2. Remove the PayPal API credentials from the config and save
3. Put the API credentials back again and save
4. clear Magento cache
5. rename `paypal._xml` back into `paypal.xml`

PS: In PayPal configuration I have set `skip_order_review_step` to NO.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the steps except to set skip order review to NO. I'll try that

Comment: @IvanPaunovic Did it solve your problem?